# Details about Icon Groups

Tags: icons

I'm playing with Mingw and embedding Icons. I add a single Icon by using windres and linking it in at compile time.

```
TRAY_ICON ICON "np.ico"
```

The Icon for the executable shows as the linked one, and opening the file with CFF explorer or similar tools show the Icon in the resource section.

When loading the Icon from within the application I use LoadIcon like below:

```
LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "TRAY_ICON");
```

Which works as expected and I can use the Icon for whatever. When looking at other executables I can see multiple Icons in the resources however. These are similar and are only different in size.

1. With multiple Icons present in the resource section, how does Windows decide which one to use when viewing the file in explorer or similar?
2. How are specific Icons selected when specifying a given Icon group?

Answer (score 0):

K, so solved both, just forgot to post an answer here.

1. Windows uses the first icon group for the program icon.
2. Icon files can contain multiple images. Use the Linux imagemagic package to merge them. Windows decides which one to use based on size.